# How to allow network connection only from Apple App Store

Tags: networking, squid, apple

I want to set up a public wireless access point in a booth that I can let anyone download apps from **Apple App Store** via iPhone/iPod/iPad only. I don't want them to surf the web or anything except downloading apps.

I figured out that **Squid-cache** might be able to help by setting some kind of access list. But how do I know which kind of connection should I allow [e.g. block by ports? or some specific hostnames?]. Any idea please??

Comment: what are you using as router/firewall/switch? Any servers that you could use?

Comment: I got a Linux server with 2 LAN interfaces. One side connected to an open shared Internet connection. Other side connected to a normal access point which I want to share Wifi with iPhone/iPod/iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Most routers have a way to either block all sites except these...sites or to allow all sites except these... sites.

I don't know the hostname Apple uses for their app store, but adding it to this list will handle the job nicely.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure whether blocking only URL is enough. I used my laptop connected to the Internet via wire and shared Internet connection via Wireless LAN. Then, I can sniff packets from my iPod touch using "wireshark" to see its behavior when trying to download an apps from App store.

Comment: Well, if you put the Apple App Store hostname into the allowed area of the router, and block all other, in theory only packets with that hostname in them will be allowed. Routers are the all mighty gate keepers of our Internet as we know it today. When routers say no, they mean, No! I'm not hacker so I can't tell about the ways to foil routers, but I'd say this method should be as good as China's  Great Firewall.